# Swift compound arithmetic operation ERROR

Tags: swift

```
var ret = -100.0 + (2.0 * 1.3) + (3.0 * 4.0) + (0.2 * 2.0 * 2.0) + 0.1 * 2.0 * 3.0
//output: Cannot invoke '+' with an argument list of type '($T24, $T31)'
```

When I perform the operation above, error occurs, it's very strange! Is it too complex for swift to compute?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but would put 0.1, 2.0, 3.0 inside () helps??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full error message can be found in the Build log in the Report Navigator:

```
main.swift:15:66: error: cannot invoke '+' with an argument list of type '($T24, $T31)'
var ret = -100.0 + (2.0 * 1.3) + (3.0 * 4.0) + (0.2 * 2.0 * 2.0) + 0.1 * 2.0 * 3.0
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.swift:15:66: note: expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time;
      consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions
var ret = -100.0 + (2.0 * 1.3) + (3.0 * 4.0) + (0.2 * 2.0 * 2.0) + 0.1 * 2.0 * 3.0
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So yes, this expression is too complex for the current (beta 6) Swift compiler.
I would suggest to file a bug report.

At present, the only workaround seems to be to split the expression in two parts,
e.g.

```
var ret = -100.0 + (2.0 * 1.3) + (3.0 * 4.0)
ret += (0.2 * 2.0 * 2.0) + 0.1 * 2.0 * 3.0
```

Of course the parentheses are not necessary here, but removing them does not solve
the problem with the original expression.

Comment: @ViktorLexington are you ironic? :D