# Defaults too complex to compile with basic '+' operator

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, nsuserdefaults

```
func updateTotalScore() -> Int {
        var totalScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        var highScoreAB1 = defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB1")

        var highScoreAB2 = defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB2")

        var highScoreAB3 = defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB3")

        var highScoreAB4 = defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB4")
        var highScoreAB5 = defaults.integerForKey("HighScoreAB5")
        var highScoreAB6 = defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB6")
        var highScoreAB7 = defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB7")
    totalScoreDefault =
      (defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB1") + defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB2")) + (defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB3") +   defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB4")) + (defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB5") + defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB6")) + defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB7") }
```

Adding multiple keys to get a total score default throws the following error. I tried grouping them together into pairs, and that did not work. Thank you in advance. This is a continuation from a post from yesterday.

Comment: First, your variables are unused in that method. Second, what is the point of  having all those parenthesis ? Simple totalScore = defaults.integerForKey("key1") + defaults.integerForKey(keyXxx) will work. Your code compile without error if I remove all those unneeded parenthesis.

Comment: even with those parenthesis the code should compile,  the problem probably comes from things like having the extra curly brace or the mispelling of totalScoreDefault , and the compiler just has no idea what is going on

Comment: thanks for that catch Knight, on the spelling, 3am coding it happens. :) , as far as the extra bracket, that is because the method was called at the end of the class so when I copied my code over must grabbed it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an addition to Logan's answer, because you are saying that you have problems with "complex expression" compiler error. This should compile:

```
func updateTotalScore() -> Int {

           let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

           let totalScoretDefault =
                 defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB1") +
                 defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB2") +
                 defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB3") +
                 defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB4") +
                 defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB5") +
                 defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB6") +
                 defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB7")

           return totalScoretDefault

}
```

Comment: at the very end I am getting a non- void return error. I am going to goggle that real quick, it does compile though, as far as the expression is concerned.

Comment: @LegacyEternal That can happen if you declare this function as `func updateTotalScore()` and try to return something. I am not sure how you are getting that error with what I've posted.

Comment: Possibly "my" placement? I have it bottom of my HUD scene, as the last method of the class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to add all of the highscores up into one UserDefault named totalScoreDefault. If so, you need to be setting the totalScoreDefault like so:

```
default.setInteger(highScoreAB1 + ... + highScoreAB7, forKey: "totalScoreDefault")

// You can also consider adding all highScores up before 
// this to make the setInteger portion look cleaner.

var totalScore = 0
for var i = 1; i < 8; i++ {
    totalScore += defaults.integerForKey("highScoreAB\(i)")
}
defaults.setInteger(totalScore, forKey: "totalScoreDefault")
```

Comment: Thank you! Much Appreciated!

Comment: I am assuming that since ++ will be depreciated I could use += on i or is this a different use case, because of the syntax??